# Get Results on based on range and combination of columns

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample DF:**

```
ID   Name        Price     Sum       
1    Apple         10      180        
2    Apple         10      100        
3    Apple         10      80         
4    Orange        12      180        
5    Orange        12      190         
6    Banana        15      50       
7    Banana        15      30
```

**Expected DF:**

```
ID   Name        Price     Sum     Result  
1    Apple         10      180      Full Match       
2    Orange        12      180      Match - High Confidence  
3    Orange        12      190      Match - High Confidence   
4    Banana        15      50       Match - Low Confidence
5    Banana        15      30       Match - Low Confidence
```

**Problem Statement:**

I need a `Result` columns which works on following conditions:

1. With a group `Name` and `Price` i.e. Name is **Apple** and Price is **10**, if the highest value is not **+- 30 range** with others then keep highest value row with result column as `Full Match` and delete others **(Sample Df - ID 1,2,3 and expected DF is only ID 1)**
2. Within a group `Name` and `Price` if it is in **+- 30 range** and also greater than 100 then result columns will be `Match - High Confidence` and no rows being deleted **(Sample Df - ID 4,5 and expected DF is ID 2,3)**
3. Within a group `Name` and `Price` if it is in **+- 30 range** and less than 60 then result columns will be `Match - Low Confidence` and no rows being deleted **(Sample Df - ID 6,7 and expected DF is ID 4,5)**

I am not able to find anything on how to solve this when there is a combination of groups involved plus the range. Any help ?

Comment: @jezrael: Any help here!!!

Comment: Sorry, I was not here, dinner time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with, you can give it a try:

```
#get absolute difference from max value
df['diff_abs']=abs(df.Sum-df.groupby(['Name','Price'])['Sum'].transform('max')) 
#check if diff less than 30 remove them
m=df.loc[df.duplicated(['Name','Price'],keep=False)&df.diff_abs.lt(30)].reset_index()
print(m)

   index  ID    Name  Price  Sum  diff_abs
0      0   1   Apple     10  180         0
1      3   4  Orange     12  180        10
2      4   5  Orange     12  190         0
3      5   6  Banana     15   50         0
4      6   7  Banana     15   30        20

c1=~m.duplicated(['Name','Price'],keep=False) #check if entry is just 1 and no dups
c2=m.duplicated(['Name','Price'],keep=False)&m.Sum.lt(60) #if dups check for less than 60
m['result']=np.select([c1,c2],\
   ['Full Match','Match - Low Confidence'],'Match - High Confidence')
print(m)

   index  ID    Name  Price  Sum  diff_abs                   result
0      0   1   Apple     10  180         0               Full Match
1      3   4  Orange     12  180        10  Match - High Confidence
2      4   5  Orange     12  190         0  Match - High Confidence
3      5   6  Banana     15   50         0   Match - Low Confidence
4      6   7  Banana     15   30        20   Match - Low Confidence
```

Comment: Getting this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'method' and 'int'` in  `df['diff_abs']=abs(df.Sum-df.groupby(['Name','Price'])['Sum'].transform('max')) ` line

Comment: It is the `minus` operation that is throwing this error

Comment: @RahulAgarwal i think data related issue, works for the example, is there spaces in the columns, if yes, `-` doesnt work. you can check for these, else @jez-offer is the best. :) !!

Comment: Actually I replaced `df.sum` with `df["sum"]` and it worked :)

Comment: @RahulAgarwal yes that is because `sum` is a method, you should avoid having methods as variables. :) I thought the column name is `Sum` , glad it worked

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
#get Series for maximal value of group
maxpergroup = df.groupby(['Name','Price'])['Sum'].transform('max')
#subtract values, get absolute values and compare by greater 30
m1 = df['Sum'].sub(maxpergroup).abs().gt(30)
#get all groups where at least one True
m11 = m1.groupby([df['Name'],df['Price']]).transform('any')
#print (m11)

#compare by another values and test if all values matching per groups
m2 = df['Sum'].gt(100)
m22 = (m2 & ~m1).groupby([df['Name'],df['Price']]).transform('all')
#print (m22)

m3 = df['Sum'].lt(60)
m33 = (m3 & ~m1).groupby([df['Name'],df['Price']]).transform('all')
#print (m33)

#create new column
masks = [m11,m22, m33]
vals = ['Full Match','Match - Low Confidence','Match - High Confidence']
df['result'] = np.select(masks, vals)

#remove unnecessary rows
df = df[~m11 | df['Sum'].eq(maxpergroup)]
print (df)
   ID    Name  Price  Sum                   result
0  1   Apple   10     180  Full Match             
3  4   Orange  12     180  Match - Low Confidence 
4  5   Orange  12     190  Match - Low Confidence 
5  6   Banana  15     50   Match - High Confidence
6  7   Banana  15     30   Match - High Confidence
```

Comment: I am getting this error `ValueError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray` in this line `df['result'] = np.select(masks, vals)`

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - It seems data related error, are data confidental?

Comment: Not that much..I can mask!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - So you can share link of data by dropbox, gdocs or similar or send data to my email from my profile.

Comment: @anky_91 - Thank you, I check your solution and seems you check values per groups?  It seems not.

Comment: @jezrael didnt get you :( yes i have commented inline what i thought. :)

Comment: @anky_91 - I think `range with others then keep highest value row with result column as Full Match and delete others (Sample Df - ID 1,2,3 and expected DF is only ID 1)` - I think OP need compare values per groups

Comment: @jezrael yes it kinda looks in the groups while getting diff and then when i am dropping the records, the less than operator doesnot look into the groups, i felt that was not required looking at the example. :) But yes you may be correct(always..!!) :)

Comment: @jezrael thats okay. to err is human. ;) but for you its very rare